# Rails - using a minified copy of the development build of React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, react-rails

I am using `react-rails` gem in order to use React within Rails. Since I upgraded `react-rails` gem version to `2.0.2`, it started giving me warning

```
application-0a65875….js:1842 Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React. When deploying React apps to production, make sure to use the production build which skips development warnings and is faster...
```

Inside `config/environments/production.rb`, I have

```
config.react.variant = :production
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you restart the server after you changed the initializer? Also `ENV['NODE_ENV']` should be sat to eq `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` but doesn't hurt to make sure it's production in both cases.

Comment: I figured out the issue. But not solved. I am using `rails-assets-react-bootstrap` gem from rails-assets.org, which has dependency on `rails-assets-react` which loads uncompressed version of react.

Is there any way we can mention which react to choose from?

Comment: Good find! Try to read their source code and check if there is a variable that you can change to get the compressed version in the pipeline. If you can't find it I suggest you fork the gem, change the source to use the compressed version and point the gem to your github repo.

Comment: You basically include the `require react` directive in your application.js file. I'm wondering what happens if you minify that with uglifier. Did you already do that? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: ^ I am doing just this. Hence the warning. React has two builds - development and production. Warning says I am using compressed version of development build.
Appreciate your help, thanks.